# Treemap in highcharts display series name and value in treemap only

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

Hi i am new to highcharts. in that in treemap displaying only series name not value. name and value displaying in tooltip. but i want to display name and value in treemap. plz if anybody knows reply me.

```
var series= [{
 type: "treemap",
 layoutAlgorithm: 'squarified',
 data: [{
    name: 'A',
    value: 6,
    colorValue: 1
 }, {
    name: 'B',
    value: 6,
    colorValue: 2
 }, {
    name: 'C',
    value: 4,
    colorValue: 3
 }, {
    name: 'D',
    value: 3,
    colorValue: 4
 }, {
    name: 'E',
    value: 2,
    colorValue: 5
 }, {
    name: 'F',
    value: 2,
    colorValue: 6
 }, {
    name: 'G',
    value: 1,
    colorValue: 7
 }]
```

}];

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.formatter) to format the labels in level 2

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/c7LaLy32/)

```
levels: [{
        level: 1,
        layoutAlgorithm: 'sliceAndDice',
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            align: 'left',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            style: {
                fontSize: '15px',
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            }
        }
    },
    {
        level: 2,
        //layoutAlgorithm: 'sliceAndDice',
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            formatter: function() {
              return this.point.options.name+" "+this.point.options.value
          },
        }
    }],
```

Comment: I wanted exact what you shared but its not working in my requirement because i used only name, color,value. so i have not used id, parent relation so please reply me how to do for only name,color,value.

Comment: so add your fiddle . Then i think there is only one level

Comment: use my `formatter` and  put inside `dataLabels` of yours it will work

Comment: Thanks @Deep 3015, Its working exact I what i wanted.

Comment: @user4383047 check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) , it is good question(it may deleted) so mark [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) as instructed